# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.__reactAutoBindMap')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working with the latest version of react.js installed by NPM. I've written this code which works when I put it through jsfiddle, but not when I try it in my own setup. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react');

var MyButton = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return ( <button onClick={this.props.onClick} >more!</button> );
    }
});

var Count = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return { counter: 0 };
    },

    increment: function(){ 
        this.setState({ 
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    },

    render: function(){
        return ( <div>
           <li>{this.state.counter}</li>
           <MyButton onClick={this.increment} />
        </div> );
    }
});

React.render( <Count />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

and then my HTML file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>what the f</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my browser I get an error saying:

```
"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.__reactAutoBindMap')
(anonymous function)"
```

and a warning that says:

```
"Warning: Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or JSX instead. See: http://fb.me/react-legacyfactory"
```

----> update:

There are two specific issues I am experiencing after searching for exact problem areas.

A. The `React.render()` function is not accepting JSX.

In order for anything to display without error I have to use: `React.render(React.createElement(Count), document.getElementById('container'));`

instead of:
`React.render( <Count />, document.getElementById('container'));`

B. Then I get an error anytime I try to access the objects properties, for example, if in the above code I comment out anything that has `this.something` in it then the code executes just fine, otherwise it gives the error:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.__reactAutoBindMap')`

both of these problems seem like they could be related to a problem with jsx, but I'm not sure why jsx would work in some ways but not others. I am able to return `<h1>hello!</h1>` without incident, but other aspects of jsx, in render for example, do not work at all... getting desperate here... is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---> update

here is my gulp file:

```
var connect = require('gulp-connect');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Used to stream bundle for further handling
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify'); 
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['app_root/js/main.js'], 
        transform: [reactify], // convert JSX to javascript
        debug: true,
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true 
    });
    var watcher  = watchify(bundler);

    return watcher
    .on('update', function () { 
        var updateStart = Date.now();
        console.log('Updating!');
        watcher.bundle() // Create new bundle that uses the cache for high performance
        .pipe(source('app_root/js/main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
        console.log('Updated!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('app_root/js/main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
// concat app to directory being served
gulp.task('conkat', function(){
    gulp.src('/src/dist/app_root/js/main.js')
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// copy index.html to served directory
gulp.task('copy', function(){
    gulp.src('app_root/index.html')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
          gulp.src('/src/dist/app_root/js/main.js')
});

// watch app directory
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('app_root/**/*.*', ['reload']);
});

// serve the dist directory
gulp.task('serveDist', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: 'dist'
    });
});

// run on change
gulp.task('reload', [ 'browserify','conkat', 'copy' ]);

// run all
gulp.task('default', [ 'browserify', 'conkat','copy', 'serveDist', 'watch' ]);
```

and heres my package.son:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies":
    {
        "gulp":"^3.8.8",
        "browserify":"^9.0.6",
        "gulp-concat":"^2.4.1",
        "react":"^0.13.1",
        "reactify":"^0.14.0",
        "watchify":"^3.1.0",
        "vinyl-source-stream":"^1.1.0",
        "react-router":"^0.13.2",
        "gulp-connect":"^2.2.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is everything in one file and declarations declared in the right order?

Comment: Everything is as you see it, the html and javascript/react files are separate files.

Comment: What version of React are you using? Are you precompiling the JSX syntax or relying on the browser transforming it? Because the line you've manually switched from `<Count />` should be the exact same result.

Comment: I'm using react 0.13.1 and I'm using browserify and reactify to precompile the jsx. ill add my gulp file and package.json too if that ill help

Comment: Can you display the rendered version of your jsx? Seems to me thats where the problem is, your jsx file looks fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.. how do i post the rendered version? what shows up in the browser is a blank screen. so there is nothing on the rendered version if that is what you mean. unless I comment out and reference to object properties, and use javascript in render rather then jsx, in that case everything renders normally. i.e. <h1>hello world!</h1> prints "hello world!" when rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I have nearly the same problem. Try use this:

```
 React.render(React.createElement(Count), document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: maybe try: 
   `React.render(React.createFactory(Count)(),document.getElementById('container'));`

Comment: nope.. I dont understand why theres all this weird work around, why doesn't it just work as noted in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You should install Reactify 1.1.x:

```
"reactify": "~1.1.x"
```